# VB NET Application Starts with Wrong Icon First Time

Tags: vb.net, icons

I have created a VB NET application that is installed with a installer project (MSI).  Installer works perfectly, app functions as designed.

On a Windows 2008 Server R2 (Standard), the first time I log in the application starts with the wrong icon/task bar group.  It starts with the IBM Tivoli command line icon or GUI icon with those options in the group.

After I close my application and open it a second time, I have the correct icon and taskbar group.

If I log into the box and start a different application, then my application, I get the correct icon/group.

Things I have tried...

- Uninstalling/reinstalling multiple times
- Confirmed my application is advertised
- Deleted the icon cache for my profile

More information (from continued trouble-shooting)...

If I set taskbar buttons to "Never Combine" I get the correct icon for my app, but not the correct group options (right click).

If I pin the IBM Tivoli command line to the taskbar, this problem goes away.  My app starts with the correct icon/group every time.

If I pin my app to the taskbar, the problem also is resolved every time.

So this problem is only occuring when neither app is pinned to the taskbar.

Another update...

This issue occurs in multiple environments (same server configuration).
This issue does not occur with a user account that did not perform the install.  Only the installing account gets the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution...

This had nothing to do with my application or IBM Tivoli, it is a bug in certain versions of Windows...

[KB 2519550](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519550)

This KB hung up the box on restart, but once I hard cycled it, the problem was resolved.